# WIA adf scanning code not Working as it should

Tags: wia

Before I start I have a little knowledge of visual basic. I can read someone elses code and convert it for my needs, but I am not a programmer.

I am trying to create a scanning program using visual basic 2010.

I have a xerox documate 3115 ADF scanner set up on my machine and have used the c# code from the following site:

http://forums.codeguru.com/showthrea...ion-(WIA)-Code

and converted it to visual basic using the following site:

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools.../csharp-to-vb/

After making some minor changes to remove errors I am able to scan one page from the adf and the program works fine.

The problem I am having is that if I have more than one page in the adf then it takes one page and stops before it ejects the page, then I have to click the scan button on my form again to eject it and take the next page. If I only put one page in the adf then it takes the page and ejects it.

I have hunted all over the net (including most wia questions on this site) for an answer but just seem to end up looking at the same few web pages.

Comment: I have checked through the properties in this part of the code:

Comment: After checking the properties in the for each loop I realised that the document handling status is set to 4 so changed the Const Value of WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_STATUS from &h1 to &h4 and now it takes all the documents from the feeder and saves them to the selected folder as I want but it doesnt stop it just keeps coming up with the out of paper HResult error and when I click ok it tries to take another sheet and gives me the error again. Does anyone know how to stop this from happening.

Comment: Hey Gazza, do you mind elaborating on how you changed WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_STATUS? I'm having very similar problems with the Xerox Documate 3220, where the handling status is set constantly to 4, whether the feeder is loaded or not.